# Convert a multiple lined string value in a column header to single line as header

Tags: excel, vba

I am having an excel file with headers. But the headers cell data having spaces and string data is displayed in two lines in a cell. Is there a way or method in VBA/macro to remove the spaces and have the header names in a single line within the each cell?.

I've tried using split() and trim() but I could not change it to a single line.

I've added the column header screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: Maybe it's because the header row is formatted into "wrap text". Try to widen the column and see if the text "Value Date" now become in one line. If yes, then just widen each column and then lower the row height so there's no space.

Comment: You could use a regex replace method in VBA and remove whitespaces and line-returns?